# Is there any way to load point cloud data directly from a pcd url?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, point-cloud-library

I am using python-pcl. I tried passing `response.content` to `pcd.load` after converting it to a `bytesIO` object, but somehow it's unable to process it. Is there any way with pcl by which a `.pcd` file can be loaded directly from a url?

I am using the following code:

```py
from pypcd.pypcd import PointCloud
import io 

response = requests.get(pcd_url)
req_content = io.BytesIO(response.content)

pc = PointCloud.from_fileobj(req_content)
print(pc)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...../algorithm.py", line 86, in <module>
    pc = PointCloud.from_fileobj(req_content)
  File "...../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pypcd/pypcd.py", line 740, in from_fileobj
    return point_cloud_from_fileobj(fileobj)
  File "...../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pypcd/pypcd.py", line 282, in point_cloud_from_fileobj
    if ln.startswith('DATA'):
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please provide more details like piece of code you already tyried which did not worked? You can also follow the tutorial to expect a short answer for your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you also put the full Traceback? Not just the last line with the error. There might be more information (ex. exact line that raised the error), so it's *always* helpful to put the entire error message.

Comment: Added entire traceback.